# For Loop does not show the all answers from the input() , in python

Tags: python

```
total = 0 

for i in range(5):
    question = int(input("Enter a number : "))
    included = input("Do you want that number included , (y/n) : ")
if included == "Y" or included == "y" :
    total = total + question

print(total)
```

This is my code and I was trying to get each number from the **question** variable and add them to the **total** if the user writes y in the second variable which is **included** , but when i print **total** , it should add the numbers together, but the output shows the last number that the user wrote

if could someone tells me the answer to my question, how I can get each number from the input in the loop, to add them together

Comment: the `if` is currently not in the `for` loop. you need to indent it

Comment: A side note: the condition can be simply `if included.lower() == 'y':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's **very simple**. I've tested you program, and you just messed up the tabs.

```
total = 0 

for i in range(5):
    question = int(input("Enter a number : "))
    included = input("Do you want that number included , (y/n) : ")
    if included == "Y" or included == "y" : # over here 
        total = total + question

print(total)
```

You see when you type anything, while loop, for loop, if statement or anything which end's with column ":", you should add tabs before each line of code which is related to loop or statement.

**Example:**

```
if name == 'John': <----------------------------------------------------,
    print('Your name is John') <------------,                           |
 ^.________ over here we have 4 spaces so this is related to statement here
```

this way "print" function will work only when statement is true (if name is john).

**I hope I explained it easy enough, if you still have some trouble with it, look at this tutorials [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-5Mf_L0UKw)**